# gnutls-cli hangs when testing an ssl connection

Tags: ssl, gnutls

I'm running the command

```
gnutls-cli -s facebook.com -p 443 --x509cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -d 999
```

and the output is

```
|<2>| p11: loaded provider 'p11-kit-trust'
|<2>| p11: loaded provider 'gnome-keyring'
|<2>| ASSERT: pkcs11.c:425
Processed 164 CA certificate(s).
Resolving 'facebook.com'...
Connecting to '173.252.120.6:443'...
|<4>| REC[0x872bac8]: Allocating epoch #0

- Simple Client Mode:
```

and then a blinking cursor, it just hangs there. Using strace, I see that after several lines of code are executed, it reaches a point where it just prints

> select(6, [0 5], NULL, NULL, {0, 50000}) = 0 (Timeout)

Over and over and over again.  I tried upgrading gnutls to 3.1.23, but the result is the same.  Running it as root doesn't change the outcome.

As a sanity check, I also ran:

```
openssl s_client -connect facebook.com:443 -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

and it does create a successful ssl connection.  Does anyone know why gnutls-cli may be doing this... or what I can do to make it not do this?  I'm trying to debug a larger issue and I think it maybe directly related to this...

```
Ubuntu 14.04
gnutls-cli 3.1.23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You command line is wrong. Instead of

```
 gnutls-cli -s facebook.com -p 443 --x509cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -d 999
```

it must be

```
 gnutls-cli -p 443 --x509cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -d 999 facebook.com
```

See usage:

```
Usage:  gnutls-cli [options] hostname
...
 -s, --starttls           Connect, establish a plain session and 
                          start TLS when EOF or a SIGALRM is 
                          received.
```

So it actually established a plain connection and waited for EOF from the terminal and only after that it would start with the SSL handshake.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: Provide `gnutls-cli` with input from *stdin*, e.g. by prefixing is with a piping `true`:

```
true | gnutls-cli -s facebook.com -p 443 --x509cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -d 999
```